# Loading an Excel file into SQL: Some blank cells are blank, others are NULL?

Tags: sql, excel, load

Pretty much the topic.

So in my Excel file I may have a column like this:

```
 COLUMN
 ======
 100
 50

 25
 100


 75
 100
 100
```

*Note that the gap rows are actually blank rows.

But when I load the file into SQL, I get something like this:

```
 COLUMN
 ======
 100
 50

 25
 100

 NULL <-- Note that it was blank in Excel
 75
 100
 100
```

How can I format the file in Excel so that it is just consistent with one way? Thanks!

Comment: Were they truly blank cells or were they zero-length strings (e.g. `""`) returned by formulas? In Excel, if you go to the top **100** value and tap Ctrl+▼, where do you end up?

Comment: Hey I think that you are right. If that's the case, how do I resolve?

Comment: It isn't clear which way you want to go; only that you want them all one way. Personally, I prefer raw values so I would lean toward truly blank cells. Otherwise an SQL query is not going to respond correctly to `WHERE [fld] IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If the cells actually contain zero-length strings, you can quickly turn these into truly blank cells by sweeping through them with [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx).

```
Sub strip_zero_length_string()
    Dim c As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Cells = .Cells.Value
        For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
            .Columns(c).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, c), _
              DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```